# How to avoid universal Rule CSS Asterisk(*)?

Tags: css

I have a table `<table></table>` and also a CSS Rule `*{margin:0;padding:0;}`

Now I want to nullify the effect of "`margin:0`" (the universal rule) over the above mentioned table. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
table#some_id {margin:10px;}
```

Btw. you should never use `* {margin:0;padding:0;}`. Rather try a [CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/116754/best-css-reset)

Comment: I checked the available code with inspect element of firebug and disabled "margin:0" in firbug which resulted in my desired result.. What could be the reason and how can this  be achieved?

Comment: Every selector has its own "importance". So if you define an ID on that table and define CSS for it, it'll get to override the default rules.

Comment: @OM The Eternity: then you may want to try table#some_id, table#some_id * { margin: auto; }... However, I'd advise you to set a specific margin because different browsers may have different ideas on what the default margin should be.

Answer (score 5):

You cannot undo it..

You have to redefine/override it.

Give a class to your table

```
<table class="normal"><tr><td>text</td></tr></table>
```

and in css use (*example values*)

```
.normal{margin:5px;padding:5px;}
```

Answer (score 4):

For all tables in your page: `table { margin: 4px; }`

For a particular CSS class of table: `table.someClass { margin: 4px; }`

For a specific table instance: `table#someId { margin: 4px; }`

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it is possible: declaring `* { margin: 0; padding: 0; }` removes the default values, and you cannot "restore" them, unless you have some known default values (you don't know which values the browser has by default).