# What does an asterisk do in a CSS property name?

Tags: css

I know what an asterisk does in a selector for CSS ([What does an Asterisk do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254701/how-to-avoid-universal-rule-css-asterisk)), but what does it do in a property name? Here is an example of CSS used by YUI. I don't know what the `*display` does.

```
.yui-button .first-child
{
    display:block;
    *display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: it's interesting in your example the *display:inline-block; because internet explorer 7, doesn't "understand" the inline-block property

Comment: @Sotiris: It does, a little. Does it all wrong, though.

Comment: @BoltClock hahahah "It does, a little"

Answer (score 178, accepted):

It is a syntax error. So in CSS, it makes the property name invalid and stops it being parsed.

Thanks to bugs in browsers, it is sometimes ignored. This effectively causes the property to apply only to browsers featuring that particular bug — IE7.

In general, it should be avoided in favour of conditional comments.

Answer (score 62):

It's an IE hack. The second declaration will be applied by IE7 and older (thus overriding the first declaration), while other browsers will ignore it and continue applying the first declaration instead.

Also, this is invalid CSS syntax.

Comment: @Jakub Pietkun: wat. Got a screenshot?

Comment: Sorry for confusion, I was mistaken. I have tested FF, Chrome and IE - "asterisked" attribute has no effect.

Answer (score 14):

its like the underscore for ie6. but for ie7

if you put the asterisk the property will only be used in ie7 and older browsers.

its an hack...

Answer (score 9):

It's one of the IE hacks. Internet Explorer parses CSS in a slightly different way, allowing for certain hacks that will be ignored in other browsers. Google for it. You can target different versions of IE with different hacks.