# Background size not set in ie

Tags: html, css

Background size not set for only IE. Image showing its original size. Any one help me how to fix it?

`CSS`:

```css
.menu_icon {
    background: url(../icons/Contacts_normal.png);
    background-size: 22px 22px; 
    background-position: left top;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    color: #999;
    font-size: 16px;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px; 
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px 0 30px;
    text-align: left;
    position: relative;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

`HTML`:

```
<div class="menu_icon ui-corner-all"></div>
```

Comment: You could refer to this thread 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Comment: See here for a brief table of browser compatibility for `background-size` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/background-size#Browser_compatibility

Comment: You try to add: *background-size: 22px 22px;

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563651/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-property-name

Comment: @RongNK just adding an asterisk to a property will not give a browser support for that property.

Comment: See also:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991623/make-background-size-work-in-ie

Answer (score -3):

Internet Explorer 7 does not support `background-size`. The only alternative is some hax that involves using an `<img>` and positioning it behind the content.

You should be using IE7 anyway. Your computer should be telling you to update.

Comment: Just because the OP is using IE7, we can't assume they are the only person accessing their website via IE7. The OP may be looking to support IE7 because of the users who come to their site.

Comment: A significantly large proportion of the population still use IE versions lower than 9 or 10. Most of them decide not to update it seems. It is impossible to ignore so many potential users for any project,big or small. That last line was completely unnecessary.

Comment: @Ronophobia: I agree. People have a right to stay on any IE version they like. I also agree that retailers have any right to charge those people that do not like to upgrade but demand a site to work for them as well. See [**Australian retailer charges customers IE 7 "Tax"**](http://www.zdnet.com/blog/networking/australian-retailer-charges-customers-ie-7-tax/2496) Everybody wins.