# Meaning of '*' before any CSS attribute

Tags: css

what is meaning of '*' before any CSS attribute like.

```
.hello
{

margin-top:5px;
*margin-top:10px;

}
```

Thanks
Vishal

Comment: Look around before you ask :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667531/what-does-a-star-preceded-property-mean-in-css

Comment: Also this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4563651/what-does-an-asterisk-do-in-a-css-property-name

Comment: Also this - http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/63

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this because it has a quick answer.  Basically it's a hack to define IE only styles.  IE will ignore the syntax error and apply the CSS rule anyway.  However I don't recommend it.  Instead use conditional comments because its safer