# Wordpress/CSS: List Style Problem

Tags: css, wordpress, list, themes, stylesheet

I am reasonably new to Wordpress custom themes but I do have some knowlege of CSS, although I am terrible at customising other peoples code which is why I have the problem I am about to explain.

I have started a website that my girlfriend and I are doing together. It uses the Simplo Wordpress theme which is pretty cool but when you add a post that has a list in it. It doesn't show the bullets on each of the items.

I have tried adding 'list-style:circle;' to a the.postItem class and a couple of other divs and classes that I thought were relevant but it doesn't work.

You can take a look for yourself, it may be easier to understand my problem that way. If you go to: http://brokeandstarving.com/234/bennos-shepherds-pie/ there is a list of ingredients and also the steps under the method is a list as well. My question is, where do I edit the CSS to make the bullets appear next to the list items?

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance,
- Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the `* {margin:0; padding:0;}` (line 10 of your css). If you want to reset CSS, [you should use a CSS reset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4254701/how-to-avoid-universal-rule-css-asterisk/4254712#4254712).

Currently the `padding:0;` rule is preventing bullets from appearing, even if you define `list-style: disc;` (line 20) or whatever for your `<ul>`s.

http://brokeandstarving.com/wp-content/themes/simplo/style.css

Comment: Oh wow! It was that simple... I just removed the padding thingy and added the list style to the .postItem and now it works! Thanks Kemo you have saved the day and the rest of my hair.

Comment: I guess we're all here to save each others hair or something :D btw. I'd recommend you to input the CSS reset anyways, because of older browsers.